# Issue with preg_match_all : Compilation failed unmatched parentheses

Tags: php, server-side, preg-match-all, regex-negation

I'm facing following warning

> preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset
>   4

when used `preg_match_all`

following is the code

```
preg_match_all('/' . $word . '/i', $text, $matches);
```

Comment: What the content of `$word`

Comment: The above pregmatch  I am trying to use is to find a word from sentence example
$word ="ban";
$text = "i can ban you";

Comment: but your example is working (https://ideone.com/8xbXaf). Can you show the exact values of `$text` and `$word` throwing the error?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch $word was matched from sever and it contained special character.
preg_quote solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there are some special characters on `$word` used in the regular expression syntax. Your `$word` contains one of the following characters: `. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : - #`. You have to quote these characters using [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

```
preg_match_all('/'.preg_quote($word).'/i', $text, $matches);
```